# ¿como encontrar una cadena de texto en una base de datos?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

tengo un wordpress instalado en local y administro la base de datos a través de phpmyadmin, como puedo hacer para encontrar una cadena de texto especifica en toda la base de datos, he encontrado soluciones donde tengo que mencionar el nombre de la columna a buscar, pero esto me llevaría mucho tiempo, existe alguna manera en la que pueda hacer una búsqueda general de dicha cadena. gracias

Comment: Mira a ver si te vale este enlace: http://informatica.iesvalledeljerteplasencia.es/wordpress/como-buscar-un-dato-en-toda-la-base-de-datos-mysql/

Comment: exporta tu base de datos solo los datos no la estructura y con un editor de texto dale buscar

Comment: gracias por las respuesta, me funciono tu respuesta Daniel